# using MYSQL data is getting in console but not rendering on HTML pages

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, express

I am creating a CRUD using MySQL, Node, AngularJS, and Express.
I am getting the response in the consoles but the data is not rendering in HTML pages.

The below-attached picture is the list of employees which is displayed on the HTML page as well as getting responses too: [Displaying all employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6Jv.png)

[image]

To get the details of the particular employee, click on show button. But by clicking on show button the data is showing in the consoles but not displaying in the HTML pages: [Displaying employee details based on id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r4Bp.png)

[image]

The code is as follows:

show.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="showEmployee()">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <p class="panel-title"> Employee Detail Information</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form>
        <div class="form-group"  ng-controller="empController">

         <label class="form-control">Name: {{ employee.name }}</label>
         <label class="form-control">Email: {{ employee.email }}</label>
         <label class="form-control">Position: {{ employee.position }}</label>
         <label class="form-control">Contact: {{ employee.contact }}</label>
         <label class="form-control">ID: {{ employee.id }}</label>
        <a href="#/employees" class="btn btn-default"> Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>     
    <div>
<div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl:'templates/list.html',
            controller:'empController'
        })
        .when('/employees', {
            templateUrl:'templates/list.html',
            controller:'empController'
        })
        .when('/employees/create', {
            templateUrl:'templates/add.html',
            controller:'empController'
        })
        .when('/employees/update/:id', {
            templateUrl:'templates/edit.html',
            controller:'empController'
        })
        .when('/employees/:id/show', {
            templateUrl:'templates/show.html',
            controller:'empController'
        });
});
```

controller.js

```
myApp.controller('empController', function($scope,$route,$routeParams,$http){
    $scope.getEmployees = function(){
        $http.get('/employees').then(function(response){
                console.log(response)
            $scope.employees = response.data;
        });
    };
    $scope.showEmployee = function(){
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.get('/employees/'+ id).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.employee = response.data;
        });
    };
    $scope.addEmployee = function(){
        $http.post('/employees/create', $scope.employee).then(function(response){
            //$scope.employee = response.data;
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
    };
    $scope.updateEmployee = function(){
        var id = $routeParams.id;
        $http.put('/employees/update/'+ id , $scope.employee).then(function(response){
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
    };
    $scope.deleteEmployee = function(id){
        var id = id;
        $http.delete('/employees/'+ id).then(function(response){
            $route.reload();
        });
    };

});
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

//start mysql connectio 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password:'12345',
    database:'Employee'

});
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
})
//end mysql connectionselected

app.get('/employees', function(req, res){

            connection.query("SELECT * FROM employees", function(err,results) {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json({"error": true});
                }
                else{
                    console.log(results);
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));

                }
            })
        //}
    //})
});

app.get('/employees/:id', function(req, res){
     console.log(req);
   connection.query('select * from employees where id=?', [req.params.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});
app.post('/employees/create', function(req, res){
     var postData  = req.body;
   connection.query('INSERT INTO employees SET ?', postData, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

app.delete('/employees/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
   connection.query('DELETE FROM `employees` WHERE `id`=?', [req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end('Record has been deleted!');
    });
});
app.put('/employees/update/:id', function(req, res){
    app.put('/employees', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('UPDATE `employees` SET `name`=?,`email`=?,`position`=?,`contact`=? where `id`=?', [req.body.name,req.body.email, req.body.position, req.body.contact, req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    }) 
    });
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server is running on port 3000..');
});
```

Can anyone please help me out?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.showEmployee = function(){
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $http.get('/employees/'+ id).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        // $scope.employee = response.data;
        $scope.employee = response.data[0];
    });
};
```